# Иконки для кнопки

Tags: python, tkinter

помогите пожалуйста исправить скрипт

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image

item = tkinter.Button(root,
                text=color,
                width=20,
                height=10,
                relief='raised',
                borderwidth=5,
                bg=color
            )

original = Image.open('images/img1.gif')
ph_im = Image.PhotoImage(original)
item.config(image=ph_im)
item.pack(side='left')
```

я использую библиотеку pillow для python33. проблема в том, что получаю такое сообщение об ошибке:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Python33\projects\svetofor\index2.py",
> line 94, in Application(root) File
> "C:\Python33\projects\svetofor\index2.py",
> line 20, in init self.make_widgets()
> File
> "C:\Python33\projects\svetofor\index2.py",
> line 50, in make_widgets ph_im =
> Image.PhotoImage(original)
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no
> attribute 'PhotoImage'

при это в документации нет примера. есть примеры по другим действиям(например изменить размер картинки, получить информацию), а про вставку картинки ничего не сказано...

Answer (score 1):

1. Картинка должна быть загружена предварительно.
2. Картинка может быть только чёрно-белой.
3. Формат картинки может быть либо xbm, либо никак. BitmapImage.
4. Класс который вы используете для картинки неприемлем.